# How to fix "couldn't read file " ": no such file or directory while executing "source.orig {}" on ns2

Tags: ns2

i'm just setting up a aodv.tcl with set mobility on it.

when i'm gonna running it in the terminal, i'm got some errors :

num_nodes is set 10
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead

couldn't read file " ": no such file or directory
  while executing
"source.orig {}".

Where do i need to fixed this errors?

This is for my project on campus, running with Network Simulation 2.35 version. i've tried on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
#setting up the variables
set mobility [lindex $argv 0]              ;# Dynamic mobility file

#setting up mobility
source $mobility
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(1) color blue"
$node_(1) color "blue"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(2) color orange"
$node_(2) color "blue"
```

Comment: »» set mobility [lindex $argv 0] «« : Looks like you have to to specify the "mobility file" at the command line, i.e. as first argument → `$ ns aodv.tcl mobility.tcl`, where "mobility.tcl" is the movement file / "the Dynamic mobility file".